# PHP Arrays. Get value from array with arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have array in PHP:

```
Array
(
  [1] => Array
    (
        [DeviceName] => Device1
        [DeviceId] => 0x0000001530A1B380
        [state] => 0
        ...
         )
  [2] => Array
    (
        [DeviceName] => Device2
        [DeviceId] => 0x0000001530A10C80
        [state] => 1
        ...
    )
  [3] => Array
    (
        [DeviceName] => Device3
        [DeviceId] => 0x0000001531471600
        [state] => 0
        ...
    )
  ...
)
```

How I can get values of `state` and `DeviceId` keys only from the array where `DeviceName` = Device2?

I have tried this, but it returns `deviceID` from another array:

```
foreach ($values as $B) {
    $B = preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', '', $B);
    if ($B['DeviceName'] == $Device) {
        print "Device ID: ".$B['DeviceId']."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Ebrahim Poursadeqi, I've tried this:  `foreach ($values as $B) {
    $B = preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', '', $B);
    if ($B['DeviceName'] == $Device) {
       print "Device ID: ".$B['DeviceId']."\n";
    }
}`
But it returns deviceID from another array =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function findDeviceAndState($arr,$deviceName){
    foreach($arr as $sample){
        if($sample['DeviceName']==$deviceName){
            return array($sample['DeviceName'],$sample['state']);
         }
    }
    return null;
}
```

in your code call function and assume your array name is `$values` and assume you have just one device with name `Device2`

```
if(($result=findDeviceAndState($values,'Device2'))!=null){
 echo 'DeviceName: '.$result[0];
 echo 'State : '.$result[1]; 
}else{
 die("Device not found!");
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in check_stardwind.php on line 46 `return [$sample['DeviceName'],$sample['DeviceID']];`

Comment: I use PHP 5.3.3 =) May be it's reason)

Comment: @whi1test I don't have this line in my codes `[$sample['DeviceName'],$sample['DeviceID'] `.  I had `[$sample['DeviceName'],$sample['state']];` you changed `$sample['state']` to `$sample['DeviceID']` ?

Comment: @whi1test  yes it is,I changed  `[]` to `array`.you can test it

Comment: @ Ebrahim Poursadeqi, Yes, now it's working! I just added `$sample = preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', '', $sample);` below foreach in function.

Comment: @ Ebrahim Poursadeqi, Could you please add condition if array with DeviceName = "Device2" is not found, then exit and echo "Device not found" ?

Comment: Ups, I make it myself: `if(($result=findDeviceAndState($values,$Device))!=null){
 echo "DeviceName: ".$result[0]. " DeviceId: ".$result[1]."\n"; 
}else{
 echo "Device ".$Device."is not found!\n";
}` **Thank you very much, brother)**

Answer (score 1):

You can simply access it using for each loop

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
  if ($row['DeviceName'] == 'Device2') {
    echo $row['DeviceId'];
    echo $row['state'];
  }
}
```

Here is the live link based on your array [Link](https://3v4l.org/IsOc6)

Comment: OMG, sorry guys! I looked into old output of my script (in txt file). That is why I was confused when DeviceID doesn't match. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Comment: Is there way to insert condition to check wether I found devices called "Device2" or not. I tried so:     `foreach ($values as $row) {
 $row = preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', '', $row);
 if (isset($row['DeviceName']) AND ($row['DeviceName'] == $Device)) {
  print "DeviceID: ".$row['DeviceId']."\n";
 }else{
  print "UNKNOWN: Device ".$Device." not found!\n";
 }
}`  I get result: `Device: HAImage1 not found.
DeviceID: 0x0000000BF239A900
Device: HAImage1 not found.
Device: HAImage1 not found.
Device: HAImage1 not found.
`  I want to receive only one reply if "HAImage1" is not found. =|

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `DeviceName` is unique, you can extract the array values and index them by `DeviceName`:

```
$result = array_column($values, null, 'DeviceName');
echo $result['Device2']['state'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're assigning `$B`, you should pass it by reference:

```
 foreach($values as &$B)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. I'd probably use a function to return an array of search results. If you expect to find multiple instance of `Device2`, you will need to loop through the array and look for matching results.

```
function findDevice2(array $devices) : array
{
    $results = [];
    foreach ($devices as $device) {
        if ($device['DeviceName'] == 'Device2') {
            $format = [
                'DeviceId' => $device['DeviceId'],
                'state' => $device['state']
            ];
            array_push($results, $format);
        }
    }
    return $results;
}

$foundSet = findDevice2($array);

var_dump($foundSet);
```

This function accepts the incoming array, loops through each record looking for the DeviceName to be Device2. Once found, it pushes the DeviceId and State into a results array to be returned. This way you end up with an array with only the results you desire.

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    'DeviceId' =>
    string(18) "0x0000001531471600"
    'state' =>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

If you aren't using PHP 7.0+, just remove the type declarations from the function.